# How to correctly parse date from Integer column in Sqlite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, date

How to correctly parse date that stored in this format in Sqlite db: 20200813?
I tried to do it like this:

```
Select strftime('%Y%m%d', 20200813, 'localtime');
```

But it returns Null.
I want to compare date in that column to current date.
How to do it correctly?

Comment: Please read the tag info ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info ) on how to provide a [mre].

Comment: strftime() formats only YYYY-MM-DD dates to other formats.Your date is not a valid date for SQLite. Use string functions like substr() to format it to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: That's a number, not a string to be parsed. Just **don't** store dates like this, either in SQLite or any other database. In other databases use the appropriate `date` types. For SQLite, you *have* to use one the [expected formats](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#:~:text=2.2.-,Date%20and%20Time%20Datatype,DD%20HH%3AMM%3ASS.) to be able to use any date-related functions.

Comment: That's not me, who was written this application and I don't have any other option than deal with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not have built-in methods to convert strings to dates. It doesn’t even have `date` data types (dates are just strings, on which you can use date functions).

You can do what you want with string functions though:

```
select
    substr(20200813, 1, 4)
    || '-' || substr(20200813, 5, 2)
    || '-' || substr(20200813, 8, 2)
```

This gives you a valid date string (formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`), against which you can then use date functions or operators.